# YamlDotNet Emit Default Value (not values)

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, default, yamldotnet

I'm currently working on a project that uses YamlDotNet for object serialization.
`SerializerBuilder().EmitDefaults().Build()` returns me a serializer which emits every property no matter if it contains the default value or not. Is there a way to specify which properties should be emitted and which should be ignored if they contain the default value?

```
[YamlMember(Alias = "disable_root")]
 public bool DisableRoot { get; set; }

[YamlMember(Alias = "resize_rootfs")]
 public bool ResizeRootFs { get; set; }
```

In the example above `DisableRoot` should be serialized no matter if it is `true`or `false`. The second property `ResizeRootFs` should only be serialized if it is `true`.